# I have a function with nested if. how can i make 'this' point to the constructor. The parent

Tags: javascript, html, binding

I am unsure about what my "this" is pointing to.

I want to include the following in my code and i would like the "this" inside  "this.getOwnerComponent()..." to point to the same "this" as a new variable i have created  which is outside the  k.getAggregation("hello..

how can i do this?

code:

```
function () {...

var c = this.getHat();
var agg = this.getOwnerComponent()

item.press: function() {
 var c = this.getHat(); //this" is not equal to the same "this" inside variable agg
}
```

Comment: oVBI needs to be there. otherwise the function fails.  I just want my  'this' inside this.getOwnerComponent().getComponentData().settings.items= "true"; to point to the same one as var c = this.getHat();.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the function. In ES6 you could use the `=>` function syntax which is always bound.
[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Instead of:

```
}.bind(oVBI));
```

Try using:

```
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Can you please show me with the snippet. Highly appreciated thanks.

Comment: oVBI needs to be there. otherwise the function fails.  I just want my  'this' inside this.getOwnerComponent().getComponentData().settings.items= "true"; to point to the same one as var c = this.getHat();.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? The suggested change is the only way to change `this` in the function body (since it is a bound function). You cannot have both.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an old fashioned constructor function if you want to account for older browsers as well.

```
function person(name){
    // properties
    this.name = name;

    this.greet = function(){
        alert("Hello, "+this.name);
    }
}

var p = new person("bob");
p.greet();
```

Comment: oVBI needs to be there. otherwise the function fails.  I just want my  'this' inside this.getOwnerComponent().getComponentData().settings.items= "true"; to point to the same one as var c = this.getHat();.